# Typical reasons why model training on GPU not faster as expected

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, cpu

I built a model on CPU.
The model is getting large.
When I try to move to GPU for training, I don't see the expected 10x-30x speed increase.
My net is a multi-layer convolution with FC at the end.

What are common reasons why GPU training can be as slow as CPU training?

Comment: What is your hardware? Did you check CPU/GPU utilization?

Comment: All depends on the complexity of computations. For simple models the benefit of GPU computations is less that the drawback of moving data between CPU and GPU (since batching is always done on the CPU). In personal experience, if an epoch takes less than tens of seconds, I don't normally see any significant boost when training on the GPU, but that would depend on man y factors.

Comment: Did you check CPU/GPU utilization?>>> How can I do that? I can check GPU ram usage ...

Comment: @NotAName: what model aspect can I measure to quantify how simple a model is? #params?

Comment: You did not include any relevant detail, actual model, dataset, or even the GPU, or CPU/GPU train times, so the duplicate is correct.

Comment: This article, for example discusses in good detail the hardware for machine learning: https://timdettmers.com/2018/12/16/deep-learning-hardware-guide/ . The key aspect is that the training data is batched on the CPU and then the batch is sent over to the GPU for calculations. How much data do you have per batch? How long does it take to transfer this amount of data to GPU and back (see article for estimates)? How does this transfer rate compare with the epoch time? If the length of transfer is comparable to the duration of epoch, you'll have limited benefit from GPU.

Comment: how can I check if opts cannot be paralyzed, looking at my computational graph?

Comment: @NotAName: so I could start by timing before/after .to(device) statements? I am using a dataloader and moving .to(device) each batch in training loop, is there any better choice?